# Control tint of individual particles

Tags: adobe, particles, after-effects

I'm creating dustclouds for a toy, using the CC Particle World and with Textured QuadPolygon, containing a bitmap.

[image]

However, the structure of the individual clouds are quite indistinguishable from each other. Is there a way to create a random tint-expression within two RGB-codes - or perhaps another way - to make the individual clouds to be a bit more visible?

Answer (score 0):

I used a PNG dustcloud instead of the JPEG-one which had a Luma Inverted Matte to create transparency - looks much better now.